# PHPUnit testing a protected static method that uses pdo

Tags: pdo, phpunit

I am very new to TDD.  I am using phpunit 7.4x-dev.  I have the following abstract class that I am trying to develop unit tests for.

```
use PDO;

abstract class Model {

    protected static function getDB() {
        static $db = null;
        if ($db === null) {

                $db = new PDO(ConfigDatabase::DSN, ConfigDatabase::USER, ConfigDatabase::PASSWORD);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }
        return $db;
    }


}
```

I have created the following test to get around the need to deal with the static protected method. And it works if I provide "ConfigureDatabase" class.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ModelTest extends TestCase {

    function newMockClass(){
        $stub = new class() extends Model{
            function getStaticMethod($methodName){
                return self::$methodName();
            }
        };        
        return $stub;

    }

    public function testDatabaseExists() {
         $stub = $this->newMockClass();
         $db = $stub->getStaticMethod('getDB');
         $this->assertInstanceOf(PDO::class,$db);         
    }

}
```

Since I do not want my tests to rely on any actual database, How would I fake the calls to PDO.

Comment: The easiest way were to not use a static method. Better use Dependency injection.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Pass the PDO object as parameter of the class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Following Dormilich suggestion I developed a database interface, just in case I decide later I do not want to use PDO.

```
interface CRUDImp {
    function __construct($datbaseBridgeLikePDO);
    ...
}
```

Next I wrote my tests for the constructor.  I used setup to make sure I was starting with a fresh mock of \PDO.

```
    class PDOWrapperTest extends TestCase {
    private $pdoMock;
    private $db;

    function setup() {
        $this->pdoMock = $this->createMock('\PDO');
        $this->db = new PDOWrapper($this->pdoMock);
    }

        public function testWrapperExists() {
            $this->pdoMock->method('getAttribute')->willReturn(\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $db = new PDOWrapper($this->pdoMock);
            $x = $db instanceof CRUDImp;

            $this->assertTrue($x);
        }

        /**
         * @expectedException \Exception
         */
        public function testNonPDOPassedToConstructor() {
            $mock = $this->createMock('\Exception');
            $x = new PDOWrapper($mock);
        }
    ...
    }
```

Since PHP is loosely typed I check to make sure that the class passed to the constructor was an instance of \PDO.  I implemented the concrete class as follows

```
class PDOWrapper implements CRUDImp {

    private $pdo;
    private $dataOutputType = \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;

    public function __construct($pdo) {

        if (!($pdo instanceof \PDO)) {
            throw new \Exception("PDOWrapper must be passed instance of \PDO");
        }

        $attr_Errmode = $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE);
        if ($attr_Errmode !== \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) {
            $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
...
}
```

Now that I have an independent database wrapper the original Model tests are at the moment trivial and no longer needed.  The abstract class Model was modified as follows:

```
abstract class Model {
    protected $database=null;

    function __construct(CRUDWrapper $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }
...
}
```

So for those not familiar with dependency injection I found the following links helpful:

http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html
https://codeinphp.github.io/post/dependency-injection-in-php/
https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html

Hope this shortens someone's work.